# Uses of saxon genitive with the word Google as the owner

Tags: possessives, possessive-s-vs-of

I would like to know which one of these expressions is the most correct and why?

> Google´s car
>
> The car of Google

When I refer to the driverless car Google has invented.

Comment: ['The Google driverless car'](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=Google+car)

Comment: You cannot ask which of two things is the **most** anything.  The superlative degree does not apply to pairs of items; the comparative degree does. Hence, **more** correct of two things.  So one might posit that one version is more correct than the other, but never most correct.  In any event, you left out a third possibility, one that @EdwinAshworth proposes: using Google as an attributive noun. That would give you now 3 possibilities, and so you could retain *most*. However, one risks treading on ice so thin as to be hallucinatory when one poses a false dilemma of correctness in language.

Comment: +1 for the modifier in the idiom. I'm going to pinch it.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, but most people would say Google's car in everyday speech.

This is usually used with particular things which are possessed by named people/companies/countries etc

> John's car
>  Anne's job
>  Britain's coast
>  America's mountains

Thus: "Let's go in John's car" but never "Let's go in the car of John."

However, you could use it for emphasis: "This car of John's is going to cost him a fortune."

The *of* construction is used in more general terms.

> The climate of the world is changing

There are also various traditional/historic uses:

> The Tower of London
>  The Leaning Tower of Pisa
>  The soup of the day

But basically they are both correct and you will be understood whichever you use.

**Edit**

The example "This car of John's..." is incorrect (see Janus comment).

A better example might be:

> All the parents were invited to the school play, even the father of
>   John and Anne, although he had been banned from attending on previous
>   occasions

This avoids the difficulty, which confuses lots of people, of whether to say:

> John's and Anne's father
>   *or* John and Anne's father

Comment: Note that what you call ‘emphasis’ is really a completely different construction: it is using _of_ as a partitive marker on what is already a possessive (Saxon or pronominal).

Comment: You're quite right, I didn't think it through :( Can you think of any instance where you would say 'car of John'?

Comment: Nope, none at all, because the _of_ genitive is not used to denote literal possession/ownership with human referents. :-)

Comment: @Janus : Not normally, but it's sometimes used as a rhetorical device, notably in book, song or film titles: Bring Me the Head of Alfredo Garcia, The Eyes of a Child, The Island of Doctor Moreau, etc.

Comment: @Terpsichore, I wouldn’t call any of those literal ownership. The first two are body parts (which is more partitive in nature), while the latter is a kind of ‘genitive of association’ (the island that is associated with Doctor Moreau) rather than possession (the island that Doctor Moreau owns).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How about Mary, mother of Jesus? That serves as a title, I suppose, does it count?

Comment: No, that’s a family relation—Jesus doesn’t _own_ Mary as his mother, it’s just a description of their (familiar) relationship to one another. Even if you force an _of_ construction on to something that clearly denotes a relationship of owner and thing owned, the ownership aspect is diminished and a more generic associative relationship is established instead: “Jesus’ sandals” are the sandals owned (and worn) by Jesus, while “the sandals of Jesus” gives a vaguer idea of association between the sandals and Jesus, but less overtly actual ownership.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  As we're on a Biblical theme, what of the phrase [The word of God](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=bks&q=%22word+of+God%22&oq=%22word+of+God%22&gs_l=serp.12...10656.16747.0.19755.13.13.0.0.0.0.129.1200.10j3.13.0....0...1c.1.39.serp..8.5.494.dG0JO_9ZEAo). Whose word is it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I’d say that’s similar to the sandals of Jesus, except here I can’t see it as literal possession even with a Saxon genitive “God’s word” (you can’t physically possess a word, it’s not a physical thing). It is a word that originates with God and is intimately associated with God, but there is no literal, physical, “I own this possession and have it in my hand” kind of ownership—to me one of the very few places where one genitive construction simply _cannot_ be used, rather than one just being more common or more natural than the other.

Comment: And yet, Google books report that [God's word](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22God%27s+word%22&num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=rg9AU8PmNeToywOei4K4Dw&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=653) is acceptable usage. God may not physically possess a word, but it is being used in a metaphorical sense. "Word" represents the teachings, the guidelines, the moral code of conduct (whatever!) of God.

Comment: The elephant in this room is that corporate names tend to be used as **attributive nouns**: *a Ford sedan, an Audi wagon, a Tesla roadster*. Neither the apostrophe-*s* clitic using *Y’s X* nor the *of* preposition form *X of Y* makes half so much sense in these cases (no pun intended) as does simply saying *the Y X*.  It’s just ***the Google car***, that’s all. Short, sweet, simple. If you want to talk about actual ownership, further convolutions will be required.